# Links and Interactive elements within Live Regions

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I was just wondering if it is allowed to have links or other interactive elements which performs an action within a live region?? The fact that the links are interactive and live regions are immediately made available to screen readers, is there a Success criteria or recommendation from WCAG that says not to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in WCAG that specifically addresses your situation but links and live regions are unrelated topics.

A live region is used when there is dynamic content on the page.  For example, if you have a page with search results and there are filters to limit the results, as you select various filters, the number of results change (dynamic) and that change should be announced to assistive technology, typically through a live region.

Another example is a "settings" page.  As you change settings, if the changes are automatically saved and a message displays saying the changes were saved, that message is dynamic (it was added to the page) and like the search result changes should be conveyed to assistive technology, again, typically through a live region.

In your situation, you have a link in a live region.  Is the text for that link dynamic?  Is there something that will cause the link text to change?  If so, then it makes sense to have the link in a live region.

Comment: Moreover, links and form controls may need to be in a live region for accessibility. If they are not on the page initially but are inserted under some conditions when the focus is after them, their container must be live to ensure users will be aware of the change.

Comment: Yes, that’s another example. I was just pointing out a few and not an exhaustive list. The new elements themselves don’t necessarily have to all be announced as long as there’s a message announced that new elements were added.